# JQuery Animate Opacity on Button Click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

This seems like it would work but I'm probably not doing it the correct way. Not looking specifically for opacity/fade but any animation functions.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('more');
    var txt = $('.more').is(':visible') ? '-' : '+';
    $(this).text(txt);
    if ($('#box').is(':visible')) {
        $('#box').animate({
            opacity: 0
        });
    } else {
        $('#box').animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jessenwells/n325v/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n325v/1/)***

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('more');
    var vis = $(this).hasClass('more'); // boolean
    $(this).text( vis ? '-' : '+' );
    $('#box').stop().animate({opacity: vis ? 0 : 1 });
});
```

After you toggle a class, test the state, has class or not, making it a `boolean` (frue/false)
Than you can easily use that boolean value inside a
*conditional operator (?:) (AKA`ternary operator`)* to do the truthy/falsy changes
of any desired method

example:

```
var iAmHappy = true;     // boolean
$('#mood').text( iAmHappy ? "Happy" : "Sad" )
          .css({ color:  iAmHappy ? "green" : "red" });
```

Comment: Great. Thats a big help for me. I will read up on conditional/ternary operations. Thanks!

Comment: @seedy here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator